# Bash sed missing \ in variable

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I have some code like

```
#!/bin/bash
DIR='/project/stnb'
HOST_CONFIG="${DIR}/config/host.$(hostname -s).php"
CT_NUMBER="$(grep -Pow --max-count=1  ct'[0-9]*'  ${HOST_CONFIG})"  #number of container 
BASH_PROFILE_PS_STING="PS1='\[\e[0;32m\]\u\[\e[0;32m\]@\[\e[0;36m\]${CT_NUMBER}\[\e[0;33m\]\w\[\e[0;36m\]\$(__git_ps1 \"(%s)\") \[\e[0m\]\$ '"
```

so I want to rewrite 1st row at "bash_profile", and try "sed"

```
sed -i "1с${BASH_PROFILE_PS_STING}" ~/.bash_profile
```

but after replacing I see only

```
PS1='[e[0;32m][e[0;32m]@[e[0;36m]ct88[e[0;33m]w[e[0;36m]$(__git_ps1 "(%s)") [e[0m]$ '
```

After googling I was try following options:

1) Use an alternate regex delimiter

```
sed -i "1s!.*!${BASH_PROFILE_PS_STING}!" ~/.bash_profile
```

2) or

```
sed -i "1c~${BASH_PROFILE_PS_STING}" ~/.bash_profile
```

---

what's wrong? 
Is it really necessary to preliminary replace \ in variable before
and replace change after operation back?

Comment: I'm having trouble working out what output you want. Could you edit your question to add example output given that input, please?

Comment: Try doubling (or tripling) the "\" chars. Good luck.

Comment: The backslash has a special meaning to `sed`; to produce a literal backslash into the script, you have to escape it first from the shell, and then also from `sed`.

Answer (score -3):

You need to specify the replacement string, like:

```
sed -i 's!OLD_STRING!NEW_STRING!' ~/.bash_profile
```